# how to move space from /dev/sda2 to /dev/sda3 in fedora 9

Tags: fedora, svn, disk-space

I have some issues to move space one /dev/sda2 to /dev/sda3 it mean

[image]

Help me to solve this issue, I need to move space from /home to /

Comment: Fedora 9 is years after EOL. You should update to something more recent.

Comment: You can’t “move space”. Move files. What are you even doing storing everything on the `/` partition.

Comment: What have you tried and what specific problem are you encountering? You understand that you can't just change the size of a physical disk, right?

Comment: These are just different partitions on the same drive so it should be fairly easy to resize them by reallocating space from /dev/sda3 to /dev/sda2. It's a relatively simple question, so I don't really understand the need for the abuse regarding his EOL OS or that (s)he might be storing files in / that is not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reallocate free space from /dev/sda3 to /dev/sda2. As one of these partitions is your root (/) you will need to do this offline. If you burn a [GParted live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php), you can boot into this and resize your partitions.

However, there is a risk that any partition resize operation may result in the loss of data so be sure you have backed up anything important.

Also, note that this would only be a temporary fix. At most I would suggest reallocating about 10GB over to your root to give you some room to manoeuvre, but you really need to address the incongruous sizes of your partitions. An 885GB root partition that is 100% full is very odd. It's entirely likely you are storing things on there that would be better placed in /home/, although currently your /home is too small at 20GB. A better ratio of parition sizes would be 20GB for root and 885GB for /home but it's difficult to see how you would address this at the moment without doing a fresh install and losing everything you currently have, unless you have some external storage you can back files up to.

Comment: `/home` isn’t always the correct location, it could also be a database, web server files or whatever. Point is: Don’t store it on the root partition, so a situation like this won’t cause the root partition to be completely full.